# storing snapshot of a rapidly changing command

Tags: macros, expansion, strings

My document uses a command which is renewed by every chapter. For some of chapters, I need to store its expansion as another variable (command). I need the actual expanded value, not the command.

To illustrate this is an MWE.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox,ifthen,xspace}

\newcommand{\subjectshort}{Compsci} % this command is used several times in the document
\newcommand{\subjectshortl}{\MakeLowercase{\subjectshort}} % this command is an workaround just for the next command
\newcommand{\abracadabra}[1]{abracadabra:#1}
\newcommand{\chaplabel}[1]{
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\thischaplabeltmp}}{
        \newcommand{\thischaplabeltmp}{\abracadabra{#1}}
    } {
    \renewcommand{\thischaplabeltmp}{\abracadabra{#1}}
}
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\thischaplabel}}{
    \newcommand{\thischaplabel}{\subjectshortl:mod:\thischaplabeltmp\xspace}
} {
\renewcommand{\thischaplabel}{\subjectshortl:mod:\thischaplabeltmp\xspace}
}
\thischaplabel
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
some content of first chapter\\
\chaplabel{Text specific to first chapter}\\
some more contents of first chapter\\
current thischaplabel = \thischaplabel\\
\expandafter\def\csname tmpstore\endcsname{\thischaplabel\xspace}
current tmpstore = \tmpstore\\ % this is the value I want to be avaibale till I redefine \tmpstore 

\chapter{Second chapter}
some content of second chapter\\
\chaplabel{Text specific to second chapter}\\
some more contents of second chapter\\
current thischaplabel = \thischaplabel\\
current tmpstore = \tmpstore\\ % i wanted the earlier expanded value avaibale here too
% writing to an auxiliary file does not produce the expected outcome as shown by the next line
%\expandafter\label{\tmpstore} % this breaks compliing

\chapter{Third chapter}
some content of third chapter\\
\chaplabel{Text specific to third chapter}\\
some more contents of third chapter\\

\chapter{Fourth chapter}
some content of fourth chapter\\
\chaplabel{Text specific to fourth chapter}\\
some more contents of fourth chapter\\
\end{document}
```

When I first call `\chaplabel{Text specific to the chapter}` inside a chapter, it creates or renews a command `\thischaplabel` and then outputs the expansion too. So far so good. However in some of the chapters I need to store the expanded value of the current `\thischaplabel` to be available a little longer, maybe for the next 4 chapters. I tried invoking the following in a relevant chapter

```
\expandafter\def\csname tmpstore\endcsname{\thischaplabel\xspace}
```

However it never seems to store the expanded value. Rather \tmpstore gets the value of the latest `\thischaplabel` .. in effect it becomes just an alias of `\thischaplabel`.

How do I use `\tmpstore` like a temporary variable holding a constant string (which itself is the expanded form of another command)?

Reason : I also need to write /tmpstore value to an auxiliary file (which is processed later). And the output I see in this aux file is the immediate expanded command instead of the final expanded (string) value. This can be seen by issuing `\expandafter\label{\tmpstore}` directive anywhere. Apart from all else, then it also does not compile correctly.

Comment: Please try to give a MWE So that we can run it and test it... I can not compile a code with your macro... I can suggest you to use the commands 
\xdef\temp{\csname\thischaplabel\xspace\endcsname}  and
 \global\expandafter\let\mytmp\temp
then I suppose you can use \mytmp where needed...

Comment: MWE added. it compiles correctly. your suggestion however does not compile.

Comment: Since you're going to redefine `\thischaplabel` anyway, why bother with `\newcommand` and `\renewcommand`? Here `\def` is the best choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\protected@edef` instead of `\def`.

The protected from of `\edef` is needed because the saved quantity of `\tmpstore`, namely `\thischapterlabel`, contains unexpandable macros in the form of `\MakeLowercase` and `\xspace`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox,ifthen,xspace}

\newcommand{\subjectshort}{Compsci} % this command is used several times in the document
\newcommand{\subjectshortl}{\MakeLowercase{\subjectshort}} % this command is an workaround just for the next command
\newcommand{\abracadabra}[1]{abracadabra:#1}
\newcommand{\chaplabel}[1]{
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\thischaplabeltmp}}{
        \newcommand{\thischaplabeltmp}{\abracadabra{#1}}
    } {
    \renewcommand{\thischaplabeltmp}{\abracadabra{#1}}
}
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\thischaplabel}}{
    \newcommand{\thischaplabel}{\subjectshortl:mod:\thischaplabeltmp\xspace}
} {
\renewcommand{\thischaplabel}{\subjectshortl:mod:\thischaplabeltmp\xspace}
}
\thischaplabel
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
some content of first chapter\\
\chaplabel{Text specific to first chapter}\\
some more contents of first chapter\\
current thischaplabel = \thischaplabel\\
\makeatletter%
\expandafter\protected@edef\csname tmpstore\endcsname{\thischaplabel\xspace}
\makeatother%
current tmpstore = \tmpstore\\ % this is the value I want to be avaibale till I redefine \tmpstore 

\chapter{Second chapter}
some content of second chapter\\
\chaplabel{Text specific to second chapter}\\
some more contents of second chapter\\
current thischaplabel = \thischaplabel\\
current tmpstore = \tmpstore\\ % i wanted the earlier expanded value available here too

\chapter{Third chapter}
some content of third chapter\\
\chaplabel{Text specific to third chapter}\\
some more contents of third chapter\\

\chapter{Fourth chapter}
some content of fourth chapter\\
\chaplabel{Text specific to fourth chapter}\\
some more contents of fourth chapter\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

The OP EDITS the question and notes that he/she would like to use `\tmpstore` as a label.  As I explained, one cannot use unexpandable material in a label.  However, here I do two things.  I disable `\xspace` with

```
\def\xspace{}% GETS RID OF ONE UNEXPANDABILITY (DISABLES \xspace}
```

(obviously, the proper approach is *not to use it*, rather than disabling it; I'm doing it here to demonstrate only) and then I come up with a more expandable form of `\MakeLowercase` in the form of

```
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \explower \tl_lower_case:n% GETS RID OF SECOND UNEXPANDABILITY
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

which I use in

```
\newcommand{\subjectshortl}{\explower{\subjectshort}} % this command is an workaround just for the next command
```

With these changes, I can get it to work with a simple `\edef`, which I can then show has no unexpanded material in it (with `\detokenize`) and use it as a `\label` argument.

The bottom line is that `\xspace` and `\MakeLowercase` are not expandable and are thus not acceptable components in a `\label` argument.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox,ifthen,xspace}

\newcommand{\subjectshort}{Compsci} % this command is used several times in the document
\newcommand{\subjectshortl}{\explower{\subjectshort}} % this command is an workaround just for the next command
\newcommand{\abracadabra}[1]{abracadabra:#1}
\newcommand{\chaplabel}[1]{
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\thischaplabeltmp}}{
        \newcommand{\thischaplabeltmp}{\abracadabra{#1}}
    } {
    \renewcommand{\thischaplabeltmp}{\abracadabra{#1}}
}
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\thischaplabel}}{
    \newcommand{\thischaplabel}{\subjectshortl:mod:\thischaplabeltmp\xspace}
} {
\renewcommand{\thischaplabel}{\subjectshortl:mod:\thischaplabeltmp\xspace}
}
\thischaplabel
}

\def\xspace{}% GETS RID OF ONE UNEXPANDABILITY (DISABLES \xspace}

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \explower \tl_lower_case:n% GETS RID OF SECOND UNEXPANDABILITY
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
some content of first chapter\\
\chaplabel{Text specific to first chapter}\\
some more contents of first chapter\\
current thischaplabel = \thischaplabel\\
\makeatletter%
\expandafter\edef\csname tmpstore\endcsname{\thischaplabel\xspace}
\makeatother%
current tmpstore = \tmpstore\\ % this is the value I want to be avaibale till I redefine \tmpstore 

\chapter{Second chapter}
some content of second chapter\\
\chaplabel{Text specific to second chapter}\\
some more contents of second chapter\\
current thischaplabel = \thischaplabel\\
current tmpstore = \tmpstore\\ % i wanted the earlier expanded value avaibale here too

Tokens of \textbackslash tmpstore:\\
\detokenize\expandafter{\tmpstore} % this breaks compliing

Using it as a label:
\expandafter\label\expandafter{\tmpstore} % this breaks compliing

\chapter{Third chapter}
some content of third chapter\\
\chaplabel{Text specific to third chapter}\\
some more contents of third chapter\\

\chapter{Fourth chapter}
some content of fourth chapter\\
\chaplabel{Text specific to fourth chapter}\\
some more contents of fourth chapter\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In the MWE, it works. However it still seems not to store a constant string value. I also need to write this value to an auxiliary file (which is processed later). And the output I see in this aux file is the immediate expanded command instead of the final expanded (string) value. This can be seen by writing `\expandafter\label{\tmpstore}` directive anywhere. Then it also does not compile correctly.

Comment: In my edited explanation, I note that `\MakeLowercase` and `\xspace` are not expandable.  I am guessing that is the root of the issue??  If not, perhaps you can add an updated MWE to your question showing the real issue.  Indeed, one can not use non-expandable material in a `\label`.  Also, `\expandafter\label{\tmpstore}` is improper...perhaps you mean `\expandafter\label\expandafter{\tmpstore}`

Comment: hmmm ... i cant do away with `\MakeLowercase`. I have edited my original question and included commented lines in MWE to highlight the issue.

Comment: @Magguu See my follow up.

Comment: hmmm ... I get some hang of it ... but I do not understand the sorcery of `\expandafter\label\expandafter{\tmpstore}` ... Why two `\expandafter`s? In my real document, the command `\abracadabra` is more complicated (it is an expl3 command which uses regex). Due to that the labels still do not work fine. I have tried all sorts of tricks overnight ... but to no avail. One more thing - what does `\detokenize` do?

Comment: @Magguu With `\expandafter\label{\tmpstore}`, what gets expanded is, literally, the `{`.  The 2nd `\expandafter` skips the `{` and expands `\tmpstore`, because `\expandafter` only skips **1 token**, and a `{` is a token.  If `\tmpstore` needs 2 layers of expansion, then `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\label\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\tmpstore}` would be required (work it through by hand to see this). `\detokenize` is like a more versatile version of `\string`, converting its argument into a literal string of catcode12 tokens.  One can `\detokenize\expandafter{...}` for a macro.